# Decaying Planets

Tags: planets, physics, atmosphere, gravity, rocky-planets

Assume there is this planet with only one type of life; a planet-wide mat of microscopic lithotrophs. These creatures eat through the surface of the planet over time, converting the surface into gas. There is no biochemical cycle that reforms the surface, they just stay in the atmosphere as waste.

My question then is under these circumstances at what size would the solid part of the planet need to shrink to for gravity to be too weak to hold onto the atmosphere causing it to blow out into space?

Comment: That depends entirely on what the planet is actually made of and what gasses it decomposes into. If, for example, one of the waste products is hydrogen, then the asnwer is "larger than the Earth".

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley for this idea it’s made of the generic elements most terrestrial are made of, hydrogen, helium, carbon, silicon, ect… As for the waste products I am not sure what exactly, I am still researching that, but I speculate oxidation reactions from the lithotrophs could convert some solids into gasses.

Comment: First, rocks are already pretty much oxidized. Earth's mantle is about half oxygen by mass. But assuming this planet was made of something like carbon with gaseous oxides...where are these lifeforms getting the oxygen?

Comment: Most terrestrial planets have _iron_ as their largest elemental contributor to their mass.  There are no iron compounds that are gasses at any reasonable temperature or pressure.

Comment: billions of years is not long enough to make a significant impact on the mass of a planet. your planet might need to be older than the universe.

Comment: @Amoeba Your setup doesn’t work. There are no silicon compounds that are gases at anything like the temperatures and pressures found on the surface of an Earth-like planet. Your lithotrophs will be excreting sand as well as gases.

Comment: If you do assume there is this planet with only one type of life; a planet-wide mat of microscopic lithotrophs, then what exactly are your lithotrophs eating? If they're the best-fed lithotrophs imaginable, into what gas are they converting the surface - or are suggesting all gases have the same wight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your planet has very light elements combined into compounds that are much heavier, and if the rocks of the planet contain a lot of those compounds containing lighter elements, then the rock eating lifeforms might eat those compounds and break them up into their components, including gases.

So mass will gradually be transferred from the lithosphere to the atmosphere.  But that should change the escape velocity of the planet only very slightly and slowly.

The gas giant planets Jupiter and Saturn are largely composed of hydrogen and Helium, but aren't losing their atmospheres into space because their escape velocities are high enough to retain their atmospheres.

On Earth, Oxygen is a major component of the rocks in the crust, formed out of solid materials which reacted with atmospheric oxygen to form new solid compounds.  Since Earth is about 30.1 percent oxygen by mass, the mantles of Earth like planets should also contain a lot of oxygen.

So if hypothetical rock eating lifeforms released free oxygen from the rocks faster than the oxygen recombined with other elements to form more rock, the amount of oxygen in the atmosphere would increase and the amount of rock would decrease.  A planet would gradually form a very massive oxygen rich atmosphere, which was very dense at the surface and extended higher above the surface.

But oxygen would not escape rapidly from the planet into space unless the planet was at the edge of being able to hold onto oxygen for geological eras of time.

So maybe you should consult *Habitable Planets For Man*, Stephen H. Dole, 1964.

https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/commercial_books/2007/RAND_CB179-1.pdf

On pages 34-35 Dole mentions a rule of thumb for calculating how long a planet can retain its atmosphere, the ratio  of the world's escape velocity divided by the Root-mean-square of the velocity of a gas in the planet's exosphere, which depends on the temperature in the exosphere.

Table 5 on page 35 gives the time it would take for the amount of gas to be reduced to 0.368 of its original amount with different values of the ratio.

If the ratio is as low as 2, the planet will lose that gas almost instantly.

If the ratio is 3, the amount of the gas will be reduced to 0.368 in a few weeks.

If the ratio is 4, the amount of the gas will be reduced to 0.368 in a few thousand years.

If the ratio is 5, the amount of the gas will be reduced to 0.368 in about a hundred  million years.

If the ratio is 6, the amount of the gas will be reduced to 0.368 in about an infinite time.

The temperature in Earth's exosphere, where gases escape into space, is several times as high as on Earth's surface, and so gases are faster in the exosphere than lower in Earth's atmosphere.

On page 54 Dole says that if a planet had had Earthlike surface temperatures while having an exosphere temperature as low as1000 Kelvin, it could retain 0.368of its original oxygen after a hundred million years if it had an escape velocity of 6.25 kilometers per second, five times 1.25 kilometers per second, the velocity of oxygen at 1000 Kelvin.

And if the amount of oxygen drops to 0.368 of he original amount in about a hundred million years, the oxygen could be replaced by various processes as a fast or faster than it was lost into space.

Dole described a world with an escape velocity of 6.25 kilometers per second as having 0.195 the mass of Earth, 0.63 times the radius of Earth, and a surface gravity of 0.49 *g*.

A world with an escape velocity of 5 kilometers per second would have only 4 times the root-mean-square velocity of Oxygen at a temperature of 1000 k, and so the amount of oxygen in he atmosphere would be reduced to 0.368 the original amount in only a few thousand years, which might be much too fast for the oxygen to be replaced.

So imagine a world where all of the oxygen in the crust and mantle rocks has been converted into gas, producing an extremely massive atmosphere.  The escape layers in the exosphere of the atmosphere might be far, far above the solid surface of the planet, and enough to have a somewhat lower escape velocity than at the surface, but still enough to take tens of millions of years to reduce the oxygen to only 0.368 of its original amount.

The ratio between the escape velocity of the planet and the velocity of the oxygen in the planet's exosphere has to change.

And a star will greatly increase its luminosity during its time on the main sequence.

> The Sun is gradually becoming hotter in its core, hotter at the surface, larger in radius, and more luminous during its time on the main sequence: since the beginning of its main sequence life, it has expanded in radius by 15% and the surface has increased in temperature from 5,620 K (5,350 °C; 9,660 °F) to 5,777 K (5,504 °C; 9,939 °F), resulting in a 48% increase in luminosity from 0.677 solar luminosities to its present-day 1.0 solar luminosity.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun#Life_phases

And the Sun will continue to increase in luminosity and temperature for a few million more years before it becomes a red giant.

So the surface of your planet will become considerably hotter over billions of years as its star evolves, and so will the exosphere of your planet's atmosphere.

The temperatures in the exospheres of Earth and other planets are believed to be  caused by light in the ultraviolet range and not by all wavelengths of light.  As a star gets more luminous it also gets hotter, which means that a higher proportion of its light will be ultraviolet.

And you might want to make the star of your planet somewhat more massive than the Sun so that it evolve to be more luminous and hotter more quickly.

The stellar wind of particles from a star can increase the atmospheric loss rate by knocking atmospheric particles away from a world.  and as a main sequence star gets hotter its stellar wind should increase.

And maybe you might want to create something which will make the star suddenly produced more ultraviolet light, like the collision of a massive object with the star.  That way the planet might lose all of its supermassive oxygen atmosphere in a few weeks or something.

There is another type of rock which also can be broken down into gases.  That rock is water ice, and many worlds in the other solar system are largely made of water rock.

Titan, the largest moon of Saturn, is largely made of water.

> Based on its bulk density of 1.88 g/cm3, Titan's composition is half ice and half rocky material.

Titan has a low escape velocity of only 2.641 kilometers per second, but has a dense, mostly nitrogen atmosphere.  It has some methane in the atmosphere, and liquid methane on the surface.

So naturally there is speculation about the possibility of lifeforms on Titan which use liquid methane in place of liquid water.

And possibly some of those lifeforms could possibly evolve some method of using the water rock on the surface, breaking it up into hydrogen and oxygen and combining it with nitrogen and/or methane to make some sort of food.  Any free oxygen produced would probably accumulate in the atmosphere, but any free hydrogen would probably rise to the exosphere and be lost into outer space.

And maybe as its star get hotter and produces more ultraviolet radiation, a Titan-like world will start to rapidly lose not only hydrogen, but also the nitrogen and oxygen in its atmosphere, eventually leading to a rapid loss of that atmosphere into space.

I note that if a small cold Titan-like world is a moon of a giant planet and its star is increasing its luminosity, the atmosphere of the  small cold Titan-like world will heat up and expand, and as it expands the upper layers might pass outside the limit where the moon's gravity is stronger than that of the planet, and the planet's gravity may pull the outer atmospheric layers out into orbit around the planet.

So possibly you might want to consider making your world a small cold world with rocks of ice and a methane based biochemistry, with water rock eating lifeforms which produce oxygen and hydrogen.  And with a star which is rapidly  becoming more luminous and hotter.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not going to go over why this would be impractical - I'm just assuming, like you are, that it's happening.

The actual answer is: it depends.

This is maybe the most common image in this site:

[image: A graphic showing escape velocities of planets, and the average speee of certain gas molecules in them]

Put your planet in the graph. Any gas above it is lost over geological time.

So the answer depends mostly on the planet's mass, size, gas composition and surface temperature. The three first parameters are defined just by the planet and its ecossystem, while the temperature factor will depend on what kind of star it orbits and how far away. But you could also have a rogue planet, which makes this way more complex!

Remember that even if you find a spot in the graph where an atmosphere is stable, some gas is still lost slowly to space due to some molecules achieving high velocities anyway (temperature is just a measure of average speeds of molecules), solar winds, quantum tunneling etc. Which means that if your planet exists for long enough to outlast our own galaxy, at some point that atmosphere is either all lost or it gets solidified from the cold of dead space.

I also just remembered that if your planet is too close to a star, or is orbiting a star and has no magnetic field, it will tend to lose its atmosphere much faster anyway due to solar winds. The graphic does not account for that, but just think of Mercury and Mars.

Finally, take this into account: turning rock into gas does not change the planet's mass, but if you eat away the rock enough the escape velocity at the surface may change. Keeping the same planetary mass, and the density of the non-gaseous parts but reducing the radius below the atmosphere will lower the surface escape velocity, moving your planet irreversibly down in the graph. At the same time, turning rock into gas also tends to be an exothermic process. This means heating the atmosphere up, which will also heat up from the increase in pressure. That increases average molecular speed and thus moves the planet to the right in the graph over time. Which causes atmospheric loss and thus a cooldown, moving the planet to the left again. Your planet may have really complex cycles where the mass and density of the atmosphere change over thousands or millions of years.

Answer (score 8):

No size. A gas made out of rock stuff has more energy than a rock, not less, so if your space bugs are eating rocks and making gas, they're doing it to *cool down*, not to fuel their metabolisms, and it'll precipitate out of the atmosphere as dust as fast as they poop it out.

Comment: Upvote on the principle of this, but in a fantastical setting the extra energy might be coming from a star's radiation. Life could use that energy to turn rock into gas.

Comment: The extra energy surely would be coming from a star's radiation, but if enough energy is coming from the star's radiation to keep the silicates from precipitating out as dust, enough energy is coming from the star's radiation to vaporize the planet without any help from space bugs (which is perfectly normal for vast regions of reality, but you don't find planets in any of those regions, because all the planet stuff that was there got vaporized instead of forming planets).

Comment: silicate rocks are made mostly of oxygen, so plants give you an example of how this could work.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the creatures turn what they eat into gas (let's skip on the plausibility of this) doesn't change the mass of the planet: what they emit as gas stays on the planet and what they absorb in their metabolism stays on the planet, resulting in 0 net mass change of the planet after each lunch.

0 net mass change means that also the gravitational well of the planet doesn't change, therefore of all the risks and worries they have, your species can avoid losing its sleep over eating the planet to outer space.

Comment: It does reduce the density, which could result in the atmosphere expanding enough that the escape velocity at the edge is reduced enough to start making a difference.

Comment: Turning rock into gas will require energy, which can be supplied via star radiation. This also means that the planet heats up over time. Given these factors the gas can eventually escape the planet just like what happens with our own atmosphere.

Answer (score 2):

The escape velocity for a planet is given by the formula:

$v_e = \sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r}}$

where:

- $v_e$ is the escape velocity,
- G is the gravitational constant (~$6.674 \times 10^{-11}m^3kg^{-1} s^{-2}$),
- M is the mass of the planet, and
- r is the radius of the planet.

However, the problem is a bit more complex than just calculating the escape velocity because the lithotrophs are reducing both the mass and the radius of the planet as they convert the surface to gas. Moreover, the type of gas produced and the temperature of the planet would also play a role in determining the speed of the gas molecules and thus their ability to escape the planet's gravity.

A simplifying assumption is to consider that the lithotrophs are reducing the planet uniformly, maintaining its spherical shape and uniform density. In this case, the mass M of the planet is proportional to the cube of its radius (M ∝ $r^3$). Then, the escape velocity becomes dependent on the square root of the radius ($v_e$ ∝ $\sqrt{r}$).

Temperature of the planet and the molecular weight of the gas will factor in as well. The average speed of a gas molecule is given by the formula:

$v_{avg} = \sqrt{\frac{8kT}{\pi m}}$

where:

- $v_{avg}$ is the average speed of the gas molecule,
- k is Boltzmann's constant (~$1.38 \times 10^{-23} J K^{-1}$),
- T is the temperature in Kelvin, and
- m is the molecular weight of the gas.

When the average speed of the gas molecules exceeds the escape velocity of the planet ($v_{avg} > v_e$), the planet would start to lose its atmosphere.

This is a simplified model and doesn't account for factors like solar wind, magnetic field of the planet, the nature of the lithotrophs' metabolism, etc., which could affect the retention of the atmosphere. Also, the process of atmosphere loss is gradual and happens over geological timescales. For a more accurate assessment, a detailed numerical simulation would be required.

Answer (score 2):

Earth (as a random, relatively well understood example of a rocky planet) is 32.1% iron, mostly in the core, and 30.1% oxygen by mass. The remainder is overwhelmingly stuff combined with the oxygen, together making up the mantle and crust.

If your lithotrophs have a source of infinite energy, they could split out the oxygen and let *that* escape with about half the mass of the rock, but at some point the increasingly dense oxygen atmosphere is going to explosively recombine with the sea of powdered magnesium, silicon, and aluminum that the rest of the rock turned into. And if it doesn't, the fresh rock will be increasingly deeply buried by the crust of reduced material the microbes produce.

The elements that rocky planets are composed of generally have few volatile compounds, and those compounds tend to 1: require rare elements like fluorine that are generally more stable in the form of very solid minerals, and 2: would make a very dense atmosphere that would not be prone to escaping in the case where you had a planet with a freakish enough composition to allow it to be converted largely into gaseous compounds.

In short, the materials that can be reasonably turned into gases at the typical temperatures of rocky planets tend not to participate much in the formation of rocky planets. They stay gases, and either they mostly leave, or what forms is a gas giant instead.